# Why the input submit button is not submitting using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, submit, fetch-api

I have this html code in django

```
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and this JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', submit_mail);


  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

    // COMPOSE EMAIL

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

    // SENT EMAIL

function submit_mail(event) {

  // Post email to API route
  fetch('/emails' , {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value,
      subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
      body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
    })
  })
  .then(response => load_mailbox('sent'));
}
```

The problem is that the submit button is not submitting, I don't know where is the problem, the submit button is supposed to call the `submit_mail` function on the JavaScript code, instead is not doing anything.

No error shows in the browser console.

PS: I'm starting with JavaScript

Comment: You need to add an on submit attribute to your form. Check out this link from w3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp.

Comment: also instead of using querySelector I recomend using ```document.getElementById``` and storing it into a variable that you can reference throughout your code.

Comment: because you forget to add an `event.preventDefault()` to avoid a page reloading ?

Comment: the problem was my browser, the cache memory or something, i run the app in incognito mode and works. thank for your help.